# Maximum Number of users for SharePoint Online Query

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online

I'm currently looking at migrating an On-Premise 2010 environment to SharePoint Online.

I see on the **[following](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for-Business-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498#__limits_for_sharepoint)** page it says there is a 300 user limit.

Could anybody elaborate on this limit, is it the total number of licensed users allowed, or the total number of currently logged in users? Is it a hard limit, or just a recommended?

We have about 350 internal users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means for the **Office 365 Business Essentials** and **Office 365 Business Premium** plans maximum of 300 user licenses can be created. In your case if you have 350 users, you should opt for some other plan which gives you 350+ , for eg: Enterprise plan which has the capacity for 500,000 users or talk to Microsoft

Comment: Thank you very much,   was me being silly, we are going for E3 plans, hadnt noticed I was looking at the normal business plans.